# Filter SQL datatable according to different parameters, without a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, select, filter

I'm building an application that needs to allow the user to filter a data table according to different filters. So, the user will have three different filter posibilites but he might use only one, or two or the three of them at the same tame.

So, let's say I have the following columns on the table:

ID (int) PK

Sede (int)

Programa (int)

Estado (int)

All of those columns will store numbers, integers. The "ID" column is the primary key, "Sede" stores 1 or 2, "Programa" is any number between 1 and 15, and "Estado" will store numbers between 1 and 13.

The user may filter the data stored in the table using any of those filters (Sede, Programa or Estado). But the might, as well, use two filters, or the three of them at the same time.

The idea is that this application works like the data filters on Excel. I created a simulated table on excel to show what I want to achieve:

[image: Image 1]
This first image shows the whole table, without applying any filter.

[image: Image 2]
Here, the user selected a filter for "Sede" and "Programa" but leaved the "Estado" filter empty. So the query returns the values that are equal to the filter, but leaves the "Estado" filter open, and brings all the records, filering only by "Sede" (1) and "Programa" (6).

[image: Image 3]
In this image, the user only selected the "Estado" filter (5), so it brings all the records that match this criteria, it doesn't matter if "Sede" or "Programa" are empty.

If I use a SELECT clasuse with a WHERE on it, it will work, but only if the three filters have a value:

```
DECLARE @sede int
DECLARE @programa int
DECLARE @estado int

SET @sede = '1'
SET @programa = '5'
SET @estado = '12'

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Inscripciones]
WHERE
([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Sede] = @sede)
AND
([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Programa] = @programa)
AND
([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Estado] = @estado)
```

I also tryed changing the "AND" for a "OR", but I can't get the desired result.

Any help will be highly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: simple way is just use a case and check whether sede or programa or estado is empty if empty use it in or clause and non empty fields should be in and clause

Comment: next idea from server side it self you can validate it , you know the table column names so pass the where clause from the server side and use a dynamic sql here , so only include the non empty fields in the where clause , from sql also you can do the same thing the only thing is you have to use dynamic sql for this sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your anwers. After reading the article posted in the comments by @SeanLange I was finally able to achieve what was needed. Using a CASE clause in the WHERE statement solves the deal. Here's the code:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [dbo].[Inscripciones] 
WHERE
    ([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Sede] = (CASE WHEN @sede = '' THEN [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Sede] ELSE @sede END))
    AND
    ([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Programa] = (CASE WHEN @programa = '' THEN [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Programa] ELSE @programa END))
    AND
    ([dbo].[Inscripciones].[Estado] = (CASE WHEN @estado = '' THEN [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Estado] ELSE @estado END))
    AND
    ([dbo].[Inscripciones].[TipoIngreso] = (CASE WHEN @tipoingreso = '' THEN [dbo].[Inscripciones].[TipoIngreso] ELSE @tipoingreso END))
```

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 4):

common problem: try using coalesce on the variable and for the 2nd value use the field name you're comparing to.  Be careful though; Ensure it's `NULL` and not `empty string` being passed!

What this does is take the first non-null value of the variable passed in or the value you're comparing to.. Thus if the value passed in is null the comparison will always return true.

```
WHERE
[dbo].[Inscripciones].[Sede] = coalesce(@sede, [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Sede])
AND
[dbo].[Inscripciones].[Programa] = coalesce(@programa, [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Programa])
AND
[dbo].[Inscripciones].[Estado] = coalesce(@estado, [dbo].[Inscripciones].[Estado])
```

If sede is null and programa and estado are populated the compare would look like...

```
?=? (or 1=1)
?=programa variable passed in
?=Estado variable passed in
```

Boa Sorte!

Comment: It is worth adding a link to this article which discusses this type of catch all query in great detail and some ways to deal with the eventual performance problems of this. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Great article @SeanLange.  a much more wholistic response with this article about performance side-effects to bigger data with this approach.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks! That article gave me all the clues to solving this.